# if $f(x)=x^x$, find $f^{(n)}(x)$ as $n→∞$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, exponentiation

Let $f(x)= x^x$. Then

$f^{(n)}(x)$ if $n=1$ is $f'(x)=x^x\,(\ln(x)+1)$.

If $n=2$, $f''(x)=x^x\,(\ln(x)+1)^2+x^{x-1}$.

If $n=3$, $f'''(x)=x^x\,(\ln(x)+1)^3+3\,x^{x-1}\ln(x)+3x^{x-1}-x^{x-2}$

and so forth.

I don't actually know if this is the proper notation to ask this question but ill give an example of where it can be applied, to additionally help people understand the purpose in asking.

for any polynomials such as $f(x)=x^2+x+1$, $f^{(n)}(x)$ as $n→∞$

If $n=1$, $f'(x)=2x+1$.

If $n=2$, $f''(x)=2$.

If $n=3$, $f'''(x)=0$
and for any $n>3$ after, $f^{(n)}(x)=0$.

I am looking for anyway to simplify the pattern that occurs as you repeatedly differentiate such as a series or sequence that utilizes $n$, or an overall simplification such as $0$, $∞$, $-∞$, or that its divergent. If divergent, which I believe is likely, would there be representative formulas for odd and even n's?

[image: Graph of Higher Order Derivatives]

Odd derivatives in green, Even in red.

Comment: If you mean for this to be about the $n$th derivative, it is more recognizable as $f^{(n)}$ than as $f^n$. The latter might mean multiplying $f(x)$ by itself (as in $\sin^2(x)$ or composing $f$ with itself.

Comment: did you try induction

Comment: If you write as $e^{x\ln(x)}$, the derivatives of the exponent are easy. But the derivatives of $e^{u(x)}$ aren't. They are polynomials in the derivatives of $u$ times $e^u$. They follow the recurrence $P_{n+1}=(P_n)'+P_nu'$. $$u';u''+u'^2;u'''+3u'u''+u'^3;u''''+3u''^2+4u'u'''+6u'^2u''+u'^4;\cdots$$ Notice that the sum of products of the orders and exponents is the same for every term.

Comment: There is a$\frac d{dx}$ option on desmos. Your nth derivative is just a Generalized [Bell Polynomials](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nth+derivative+exp%28x+lnx%29+)